# How to change current database to another?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Java program connection to a MySQL database, how can I change the current database to a different one on the same connection?

I connect to MySQL like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+server+"/",log,pass);
```

After some operations I want to connect to a different mysql database on the same connection.  How can I do that?

I tried to use:

```
Statement stat= con.createStatement();
ResultSet r=stat.executeQuery("use mysql");
```

But that does not change the database to be used.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As described in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) you need to use `Connection.setCatalog()` to switch to another database. It also explicitly says that you should **not** execute a `USE <databasename>` to switch.

The reason for this warning is that JDBC is a generic interface to databases and therefor provides methods for most common tasks, including switching `catalogs` (or `databases` as they are in MySQL). The JDBC specification/javadoc also explicitly says that people should use the API over database specific commands (if both are available). There are several reasons for this: 1) it promotes database-independent code, and 2) the driver might do additional things internally in response to one of the API methods. Using database specific commands might cause the driver to misbehave because its internal state does not match the database state.

A call to [`setCatalog(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-) will not affect existing statements, as specified in the JDBC API documentation:

> Calling `setCatalog` has no effect on previously created or prepared `Statement` objects. It is implementation defined whether a DBMS prepare operation takes place immediately when the `Connection` method `prepareStatement` or `prepareCall` is invoked. For maximum portability, `setCatalog` should be called before a `Statement` is created or prepared.

Comment: It should be added that statements that were created before `Connection.setCatalog()` was called will still access the earlier database.

Comment: @Max Do you know if that is specified in the JDBC specification or is it a MySQL implementation specific rule? I normally work with Firebird and as it doesn't have catalogs I usually gloss over these kinds of details ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have no idea to be honest. I just tried switching databases like you suggested and it worked only after also recreating the statement.

Comment: @Max Ok, just looked it up: it is specified in the API doc. I will add a reference to it in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can prefix the database name on your table names like this.

For example: `db1 has table1` and `db2 has table2`

```
select * from db1.table1, db2.table2;
```

This will allow you to do cross database queries