# JDBC "Error in MySQL Syntax" when trying to switch to (USE) a database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been trying to use this code to create a table in a database that the code before this created successfully.

```
//Creates "Parts" Table if it's not already created.
public void createTableIfNecessary() throws SQLException{
String createString =
        "USE inventory; " +
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts " +
                "(part_name TEXT NOT NULL, remaining_amt INT NOT NULL, " +
                "restock_amt INT, barcode TEXT, location TEXT, part_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT);";
Statement createTable = this.con.createStatement();
createTable.execute(createString);
System.out.println("Table created or already existed: Parts");
}
```

My code to connect to the Database server:

```
    try{Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");} catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.con = null;
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", this.userName);
    connectionProps.put("password", this.password);
    this.con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + this.serverName + ":" + this.portNumber + "/", connectionProps);
    System.out.println("Connected to MySQL Database Server");
```

(This works, but it may be helpful to see)

My Error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts (part_name TEXT NOT NULL, remaining_amt INT NOT' at line 1
```

I Assume it is just my incompetence with MySQL, but maybe someone here can see my syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `USE inventory;` statement is not appropriate in the context of a JDBC connection.  You need to use [Connection#setCatalog()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog(java.lang.String)) to switch to a particular db.  For more details, see

[Java, how to change current database to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433326/java-how-to-change-current-database-to-another)

So do that and remove the USE clause from your SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was never able to find that answer. I'll mark this as correct in a few minutes.

Comment: Although it is correct that you shouldn't use `USE ...` in JDBC, it is not - as far as I can tell - the cause of this exception. More likely the cause is that the OP is executing two statements at once, which is not allowed by JDBC and therefor only works if you explicitly enable it in the Connector/J driver with a connection property.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for that answer. I think that really was the problem here and I must have missed that in the documentation!

Answer (score 1):

For auto_increment column in mysql, it has to be indexed. So you have to index `part_id` by making it a primary key or unique.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts
(part_name TEXT NOT NULL, 
 remaining_amt INT NOT NULL, 
 restock_amt INT, 
 barcode TEXT, 
 location TEXT, 
 part_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
primary key (part_id));
```