# Checking existence of database and a table in it: `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When using jdbc for mysql, I want to first check if an database and a table in it both exist, before inserting some tuple into the table. The following code is my attempt.

1. Does `conn.setCatalog("STUDENTS")` set the current database to database `STUDENTS`?
2. If I have switched the current database to `STUDENTS`, why does running `st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE student")` throw `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`?
3. Are my ways of checking existence of database and table correct? Are there better ways?

Thanks.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//Open a connection                                                                                                                                                    
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);                                      

//Execute a query                                                                                                                                                      
Statement st = conn.createStatement();

// check existence of database  STUDENTS                                                                                                                                        
DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet databases = dbm.getCatalogs();
boolean hasDB = false;
while (databases.next()){
    String databaseName = databases.getString(1);
    if (databaseName.equals("STUDENTS")){
        hasDB = true;
        break;}
}
if (!hasDB){
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS");
    System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
}
conn.setCatalog("STUDENTS"); // Can this set the current database to STUDENTS?

// Check existence of table `student` in database `STUDENTS`
ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "student", null);
if (! tables.next()){
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE student"); // java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    System.out.println("Table created successfully...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue. One problem was that `CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS` was creating a database named "students" (lower case) which was not found by the code block

```java
while (databases.next()){
    String databaseName = databases.getString(1);
    System.out.println(databaseName);
    if (databaseName.equals("STUDENTS")) {
        hasDB = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

because `.equals` performs a case-sensitive comparison. My code worked when I changed it to `.equalsIgnoreCase`

```java
while (databases.next()){
    String databaseName = databases.getString(1);
    System.out.println(databaseName);
    if (databaseName.equalsIgnoreCase("STUDENTS")) {
        hasDB = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, that wasn't the cause of the error. That was occurring because you were using the `Statement` object `st` that was created *before* the `setCatalog` call, so it still wasn't "pointing" to a database (catalog). As mentioned in [this comment to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433326/java-how-to-change-current-database-to-another#comment37217189_13433382)

> statements that were created before `Connection.setCatalog()` was called will still access the earlier database.

(in this case, no database).

The fix was to re-create the `st` object before trying to `CREATE TABLE`

```java
if (! tables.next()) {
    // create a new Statement object that recognizes the setCatalog change
    st = conn.createStatement();  
    st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE student (id INT PRIMARY KEY)");  // now no error
    System.out.println("Table created successfully...");
}
```